# Can VirtualBox's tools automatically hide the Windows taskbar for seamless mode?

Tags: virtualbox, taskbar, seamless

When I switch to seamless mode in VirtualBox the Windows taskbar appears right above the Mac OS X Dock. It's very annoying and makes seamless mode pretty much unusable.

Is there a way to configure VirtualBox to hide the taskbar automatically when switching to seamless mode?

Answer (score 1):

One option (which may be XP-specific) is drag Windows taskbar to the top of your OS-X screen where it will dock just under the menu-bar.  Then enable taskbar-hiding in Windows and the taksbar will shrink down to just a line of pixels until you mouse over it.
While this isn't exactly what you asked for - for VBox to hide the taskbar; this would be Windows doing the hiding -- it would achieve the same visual result.

Comment: Another option like that is to auto-hide the taskbar and move the Dock to the left. However, that's really not the functionality I am looking for. The problem is that the VirtualBox team just doesn't react to forum posts. I have already asked for a feature and offered a bounty and never even got a reply. I would gladly pay a few thousand dollars to the team if they would implement one or two features I personally need and other VM products already offer (or, in the case of VMware, used to offer).

Answer (score 0):

Open properties of the taskbar and untick "Taskbar always on top". I have however found that I occasionally need to redo this